# ExtJS 4 using Ext.form.field.File instead Ext.Form.Panel how to submit

Tags: php, extjs

I'm using Ext.Form.Panel successfully but I want to use Ext.form.field.File this time. I was able to submit and upload the data putting the field.file info a form.Panlen which I think is not the only option. For now I have:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.File', {
                            id: 'ala-bala',
                            name: 'doc',
                            width: 300,
                            buttonOnly: true,
                            hideLabel: true,
                            listeners: {
                                'change': function(fb, v){
                                    var el = Ext.getCmp('ala-bala-nica');
                                    el.update('<b>Selected:</b> '+v);
```

which is part of my docked toolbar and I also have a button:

```
xtype:'button',
                    icon: g_settings.iconUrl + 'add-icon.png',
                    text: 'Add File',
//                  handler: this._addDocument
                    handler: function() { 
                        var form = Ext.getCmp('ala-bala').getRawValue();
//                      if(form.isValid()){
                            form.submit({
                                }
                            }
```

obviously I can not use `form.submit` with this, but I hope there's a way to keep my form.field.File and still be able to submit and upload my files. Just can't figure it out.

Thanks

Leron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was dealing with the similar problem I was basically creating an dummy form and calling `submit()` on this form. Something like this:

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
  items: [ my_file_field ]
});

form.getForm().submit({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'myservice.url',
  ...
});
```

Comment: yeah, this is what I did at first too. But all the buttons are in a toolbar and when I make a panel there and add an Upload button for some reason it gets under the `browse..` button of the file.Field and the toolbar becomes way to wide. I either have to align the both buttons on the same row, or I need to pass the submit event to another one. Not able to do either of those too at the moment. How did you add the upload button?

Comment: you don't need to have two buttons... just one will do

Comment: Hmm, could you help me here? I get one button which i use to browse the system by default it's called `Browse..` how can I submit by will with only this button, or you mean to submit on selection without any further confirmation, or I don't get you right?

Comment: Yes. you have just one button - user clicks it, selects file, presses OK - you get 'change' event - you submit the form

Comment: Hmm, yeah, this will work, but I thin there must be way to submit it from another button. But yet again thanks for the feedback. Useful as always!! :)

Comment: You can submit it from another button - no problem. I just don't think you need additional step in this case

Comment: Well, If we assue I need this step how do you suggest to do this. Above I tried to describe where I'm at, If I use second button in order to submit with form.submit I have to put the button inside the form.Panel and thus It gets too wide because I the second button always stays below the browse button. And if i put the second button outside the panel then I can not fire an event to submit the form...

Comment: What you can do is - create one button 'Browse...', create a second one - outside the form. Matter of fact - don't create a form at all. When user press second button - you create a dummy form (as I described) and pass first button element to the `items[]` array. Then submit this dummy form

Comment: Hmm, this may do the trick. Thanks gonna try both ways right away.Have a nice day! :)